# GitLab CI/CD - Enable test pipeline for merge-requests

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I have created a deployment pipeline for my project which works great. Now i want that whenever a developer working on the project submits a merge request, test pipeline should run on that merge request to validate the changes being proposed.

I added the following in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test: 
  stage: test
  only:
    - merge-requests
  tags:
    - ide
  script:
    ...

deploy: 
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - ide
  script:
    ...
```

However, no pipelines run when merge requests are created. Please advise on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `merge-requests` with `merge_requests` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently available as you mention, please see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23902 for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I've resolved using this

```
build_mr_job:
  stage: build
  script:
  - 'echo script'
  only:
    refs:
      - merge_requests
```

I've found the answer here
[How to use GitLab CI only:changes with only:refs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167844/how-to-use-gitlab-ci-onlychanges-with-onlyrefs)