# How to use GitLab CI only:changes with only:refs?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration has a job like:

```
Lint dummy:
  stage: prepare
  tags: [my-tag]
  only:
    refs: [merge_requests]
    changes: [Thorfile]
  script: "/bin/true"
```

The only difference from the real job is the `tags`. Everything else is exactly the same.

Yes, when creating a merge request where `Thorfile` has **not** been changed, the "Lint dummy" job is still created.

From the documentation as of 2019.03.14 (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#using-changes-with-merge_requests)

> With pipelines for merge requests, make it possible to define if a job should be created base on files modified in a merge request.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> docker build service one:
>   script: docker build -t my-service-one-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
>   only:
>     refs:
>       - merge_requests
>     changes:
>       - Dockerfile
> ```

I am using GitLab 11.7.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for only:changes will be available in the next release:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/24490

Edit:

released now (version 11.9). here is the documentation:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#using-changes-with-merge_requests